# Not able to align button to the right in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How to align button to the right in the linear layout in android.
The button just sticks next to the textView in the layout.

This is my xml file.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <com.aavishkaar.quikies.widget.TypedfacedTextView
            xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aavishkaar.qui"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Bluetooth"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
           android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            your_namespace:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:singleLine="false"
            />

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:id="@+id/blue0"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="OFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light"

            />

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:id="@+id/blue1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="ON"
           android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light"
            />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout. and add a toParentRight="true" property to your button

Comment: Actually i have 2 buttons, and aligning them to the right makes them overlap. How to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Add a spacer view:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

<com.aavishkaar.quikies.widget.TypedfacedTextView
        xmlns:your_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.aavishkaar.qui"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Bluetooth"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        your_namespace:typeface="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:singleLine="false"
        />

<!-- ADD THIS BELOW -->

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue0"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_light"

        />


<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:id="@+id/blue1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="ON"
       android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light"
        />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actually i have an textView also, so using this method would align it too. I got the solution using relativeLayout, Thank you. :)